# Backbone collection empty issue

Tags: backbone.js

```
fetch: function() { 
        var self = this;
        self.each(function(track) {
            if(track) {
                track.destroy();
            }
        });
        Backbone.sync('fetch', this, {
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    if(response.clips.length > 0) {
                        SpinnerOn();
                        for (i = 0; i < response.clips.length; i++) {
                            self.loadcount++;
                            self.loadFile(response.clips[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

On the fetch above i am trying to empty the collection but it is not emptying the first record in the collection ,the above is for sync operation i am loading the saved datas from database.

Comment: *"it is not emptying the first record in the collection"* - does it remove other records? Maybe first one is coming back as part of your fetch..?

Comment: Note that the `each()` may cause unexpected results because it's iterator is `remove()`ing models it's currently iterating over. (I assume this explains the weird `if (track)`.) I'd use `while (this.length) { this.at(0).destroy() }`. Further, `destroy()` (as long as the models are persisted) _will_ `DELETE` the models and is async, your code will shoot many requests and your backend might be unable to handle them properly. Investigate on these findings. Please add the implementation of `loadFile()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @try-catch-finally users comment i am writing this , 100% this will work out.

```
fetch: function() { 
    var self = this;
    while(self.length) { self.at(0).destroy() }
    Backbone.sync('fetch', this, {
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                if(response.clips.length > 0) {
                    SpinnerOn();
                    for (i = 0; i < response.clips.length; i++) {
                        self.loadcount++;
                        self.loadFile(response.clips[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

while(self.length) { self.at(0).destroy() }  this will destroy all the models in collection